# Spring validation not inside web controllers

Tags: spring

I want to use validation not with web controllers. Suppose I have a class Person

```
public class Person {
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    //getters and setters
...
}
```

Also I have a validator class:

```
public class PersonValidator implements Validator {

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
    return Person.class.equals(clazz);
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
    ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "name", "name.empty");
    ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "surname",
        "surname.empty");
    }
}
```

How I can use this validator for example in console application? Or validation is only for web application in spring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the validation tools in a console application. You simply need to call `ValidationUtils.invokeValidator(validator, object, errors)`. Your main concern would be having a suitable [Errors](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/Errors.html) instance. You would probably end up using [BeanPropertyBindingResult](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/BeanPropertyBindingResult.html), or subclassing [AbstractErrors](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/AbstractErrors.html).

You probably know, but you should consult the Spring [reference](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#validator) and [javadoc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/).

Rough guess at untested code:

```
Person person = new Person();
Errors errors = new BeanPropertyBindingResult(person, "person");
ValidationUtuls.invokeValidator(new PersonValidator(), person, errors);
if (errors.hasErrors()) { ... }
```

Out of interest, why are you using Spring validation in preference to [javax.validation](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/validation/package-summary.html)? I've found that it's generally easier to use the javax.validaton/[JSR-303](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=303) API. [Hibernate Validator](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/validator.html) is the reference implementation and [Spring integrates with JSR-303](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#validation-beanvalidation-overview).

Comment: JSR-303 does not support validation groups.